# I want to open new file through a string in the editor of Sublime, how to realize it?

Tags: plugins, sublimetext2, sublimetext

Like 'ctrl' + 'left click' in eclipse, I want to do the similar things to open relative file.

For example, I have a line of comment in Sublime editor like this:

<#-- "student.htm" -->

I move mouse onto the "student.htm", then 'ctrl' + 'left click' to open the file student.htm.
How can I realize it? Or if there are other ways to do it conveniently?

Thank you for your advices.

Answer (score 1):

Try this plugin (and reassign the default key binding to suit)

https://github.com/SublimeText/Open-Include